# How to display data of each point on tooltip by onclick inside line chart points in flutter?

Tags: flutter, graph, charts, onclick, tooltip

[image: I want something like this]

I would like to display the data value on clicking on each line chart point. Is it possible to use the charts_flutter library to display this tooltip?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use TouchTooltipData, below link clearly explain how to use TouchtoolTip on Charts   [fl_chart](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/repo_files/documentations/line_chart.md#fldotdata)